Breadboard connection problem

The schematic shown is for an electroscope.
{Source of the schematic: https://www.electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/electronic-electroscope?unapproved=346023&moderation-hash=859fcc755a85adc6c1266c2f9bb41a1d#comment-346023 }
My question is, how do we connect the part circled with red?

Assume that we have connected anything below the greyish highlight {except the region highlighted red}.
Image of the actual breadboard connection thus far:

Another question, how to know the polarity of C4 from the schematic, or in general any other capacitor in this diagram?
Thank you in advance.

What particular problem are you experiencing in respect of your first question. What makes you think C4 needs to be polarized?

@Andyaka we got a capacitor having a polarity, so which direction should it be connected?
Or shall we get another capacitor not polarized?

C4 is 0.1 uF - at that value, it would probably be a non-polarized ceramic capacitor so there would be no polarity to consider.  You generally only have to watch the polarity on electrolytic capacitors.

If only one standard-size breadboard is too small to accommodate the whole circuit, you can get a giant-size breadboard or cascade two standard-sized ones.

Ok will use the ceramic capacitors then.
Thanks.
@liaifat85 yeah we initially thought one is enough but it turns out not to be, so we will probably cascade two later.

OT: Driving LEDs without current limiting diodes calls for disaster (for the LEDs).

Just my 2¢: The capacitors C1 and C6 are kind of useless here because they are in series with very much smaller parasitic capacitance of 1N4148 (~4pF) diodes D1 and D4 in reverse bias. You won’t notice much difference whether you add or remove those C1 and C6.

OT: The schematic has separate blocks for the two mono-flops in the single 556, please note the reference. Your breadboard uses two 556.

@MxDiodePN - Hi, There are problems with both you & your friend posting about the same project (it seems to be the same actual breadboard, judging by the component types & locations common between the images): (a) since the questions overlap, you both risk having questions closed as duplicates (and perhaps annoy people here); (b) the accounts could appear to be multiple accounts by one person, which has a whole set of restrictions itself - breaking any of those restrictions can have consequences. || I recommend just one of you posting from now on.

@thebusybee Generally agree, but unless he goes nuts with the npn replacement he's not likely to get more than 20 mA. Probably closer to 10.

@BlairFonville Well, yes, just because of the base series resistors. But beginners tend to copy such designs without thought. And so the brightness of the LEDs depends heavily on the specific LED AND the individual gain of its transistor. This is far from good.

It's hard to judge, but it looks like you have some bad connections.
For example, what pin is this?

You have it connected to the cathode of a 1n4148, but it has to be one of these:

Pin 7 (of either IC): in which case it is GND pin
Pin 14 (of either IC): in which case it is Vcc

(depending on the orientation of the part... it's hard to see in the photo. I believe it is pin 14.)
I'm guessing it is the quad NAND? But that would mean you have pin 12 going through one of your 100k resistors, whereas it should be connected to a diode.
It appears to me that you are treating it like it is Pin 1. Then the next two adjacent pins would make some sense.
Correct me if I'm wrong on this, and I'll delete the answer. Breadboard photos are hard to work with.
Otherwise, I would suggest cleaning up your current board, before adding new connections.
And I would guess that you don't have a polarized 0.1 uF capacitor. The one you currently have on the board is ceramic.

Thanks for the suggestions, that helped a lot; yes these connections were indeed a mistake {still beginners with using breadboard}.

@MxDiodePN Sure, but to be clear, it appears that you are counting the pins wrong. That doesn't look fixed in your new (closed) post. So, from what I can tell, you are hooking up signals to all the wrong pins. Pin 1 is bottom left. Not top left.

Correction: it does look like you may have corrected some of those issues. You seem to be missing Vcc and ground though. And as others have said: 1. you can't arbitrarily choose capacitance values.  2. building a sensitive circuit on a breadboard is challenging (if it's possible.) And I would highly recommend adding some large capacitors between power and ground going into the breadboard. Maybe a 220 uF + 10 uF.

I can't really tell what you have connected to your breadboard so far (because I'm the type of person where I need to do it myself to know where everything is... it's not you, it's me) but here's how to connect each individual component within your red circled region:

One end R10 should be connected in series with pins 12 and 13 of T2, while the other end of R10 should be in series with R9 and R8.

One end of both R9 and R8 should be in series with pin 1 of T3 and pin 2 of N1, while the other end of R9 and R8 should be in series of C4, where both ends of C4 should be "between" the latter ends of R9 and R8 and also in series with pin 8 of T3.

Pin 3 of N1 should in series with R7 and pin 2 of T3.


When I say "in series", I'm saying that they should share the same row on the breadboard. You may have to create a longer series by connecting one connection (either with a jumper wire or a pin from one of your components) from one row of the breadboard to another to elongate your row to make sure everything is still in series.

Thanks, will try that.
